# Find all files in directory which has ^@ control M in it

Tags: list, file, chars

I have 200 odd file in a directory. Many files have ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@ characters in it.
I have to first find all the files which have these special characters and list it.
Then take a back up of those files and delete the special characters in those files.

i tried all the below commands.
`od /Root/sources/filename | grep ' 000'` --> shows there are special chars in the one file

`find /Root/sources/filename -type f` -->list all the files in my directory

Have to club these 2 and list out only file names which has these special characters.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question.

Comment: Is `^@` a special character? Because I can `echo test>^@` and `cat ^@` and `rm ^@` with no problem. Where does control M from the title come into it?

Comment: I read its Ctrl+M which is displayed as ^@ in vi mode.

Comment: Also to add to this,^@ when read in Informatica gives an Error as Nulls Not Allowed.

Comment: Hi, any help on this issue?